# Error, Unknown Error while connecting database to Unity WebGL Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I would like to ask, why I get an error in database while I build my Unity project to WebGL but no error to APK build. Here is the image on WebGL build that shown an error:
[image]

And this is the image on APK build that success:
[image]

And this is my C# Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class database : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string user = "", name = "";
    private string password = "", rePass = "", message = "";
    private bool register = false;

private void OnGUI()
{
    if (message != "")
    {
        GUILayout.Box(message);
    }

    if (register)
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Username");
        user = GUILayout.TextField(user);
        GUILayout.Label("Name");
        name = GUILayout.TextField(name);
        GUILayout.Label("Password");
        password = GUILayout.PasswordField(password, "*"[0]);
        GUILayout.Label("Re-Password");
        rePass = GUILayout.PasswordField(rePass, "*"[0]);

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        if(GUILayout.Button("Back"))
        {
            register = false;
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Register"))
        {
            message = "";
            if (user == "" || name == "" || password == "")
                message += "Please Enter All The Fields \n";
            else
            {
                if (password == rePass)
                {
                    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
                    form.AddField("user", user);
                    form.AddField("name", name);
                    form.AddField("password", password);
                    WWW w = new WWW("http://somethingnotright.dx.am/register.php", form);
                    StartCoroutine(registerFunc(w));
                }
                else
                    message += "Your Password Does Not Match \n";
            }
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
    else
    {
        GUILayout.Label("User:");
        user = GUILayout.TextField(user);
        GUILayout.Label("Password:");
        password = GUILayout.PasswordField(password, "*"[0]);

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        if(GUILayout.Button("Login"))
        {
            message = "";
            if (user == "" || password == "")
            {
                message += "Please Enter All The Fields \n";
            }
            else
            {
                WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
                form.AddField("user", user);
                form.AddField("password", password);
                WWW w = new WWW("http://somethingnotright.dx.am/login.php", form);
                StartCoroutine(login(w));
            }
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Register"))
        {
            register = true;
        }

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
}

IEnumerator login(WWW w)
{
    yield return w;
    if (w.error == null)
    {
        if (w.text == "login-SUCCESS")
        {
            print("Yatta");
            Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
        }
        else
        {
            message += w.text;
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        message += "Error: " + w.error + "\n";
    }
}

IEnumerator registerFunc(WWW w)
{
    yield return w;
    if(w.error==null)
    {
        message += w.text;
    }
    else
    {
        message += "Error: " + w.error + "\n";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when does the error occur? stacktrace?

Comment: when I click register, there should be something like "user created" like the APK build. But when I click register in WebGL build, it shows an error "Error: Unknown Error" as shown at the image.

Comment: so what does the stacktrace show you?